# .net Framework won't install on Server 2003 SP2 x64

Tags: windows-server-2003, 64-bit, .net-3.5, dotnet-framework

When I install the .net Framework 3.5 SP1 on my rental VPS, I get the message that setup has failed. It's a Server 2003 VPS w/ SP2 installed (64-bit). The .net Framework v 2.0 installed correctly.

How do I fix this?

This is the installation log:

```
[03/10/10,07:44:46] Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0a x64: [2] Failed to fetch setup file in CBaseComponent::PreInstall()
[03/10/10,07:44:47] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147467260.
[03/10/10,07:44:48] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::RunInstallPhase() - Call to Pre/Install/Post for InstallComponents failed
[03/10/10,07:44:49] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::RunInstallPhaseAndCheckResults() - RunInstallPhase() returned a NULL piActionResults
[03/10/10,07:44:49] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::RunInstallFromList() - RunInstallPhaseAndCheckResults failed [2]
[03/10/10,07:44:51] setup.exe: [2] ISetupManager::RunInstallLists(IP_PREINSTALL failed in ISetupManager::RunInstallFromThread()
[03/10/10,07:44:52] setup.exe: [2] ISetupManager::RunInstallFromThread() failed in ISetupManager::RunInstall()
[03/10/10,07:44:53] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::Run() - Call to RunInstall() failed
[03/10/10,07:44:59] WapUI: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0a x64 is not installed.
[03/10/10,07:45:00] WapUI: [2] DepCheck indicates XPSEPSC x64 Installer was not attempted to be installed.
[03/10/10,07:45:02] WapUI: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SP2 x64 was not attempted to be installed.
[03/10/10,07:45:02] WapUI: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 (x64) 'package' was not attempted to be installed.
[03/11/10,14:19:23] Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SP2 x64: [2] Error: Installation failed for component Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SP2 x64. MSI returned error code 1604
[03/11/10,14:26:14] WapUI: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SP2 x64 is not installed.
```

Thanks!!
Yvan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you may have installed the 32-bit .NET 2.0.  The .NET 3.5 SP1 installer will attempt to patch .NET 2 and it's saying it can't find the 64-bit .NET 2.0.

Comment: so basically: uninstall .net 2.0 and try again?

Comment: @Yvan: yeah, that's where I'd start.  Make sure you have the x64 installer.  Here's the download page: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=b44a0000-acf8-4fa1-affb-40e78d788b00

Comment: Especially the comment in the line "[03/10/10,07:44:59] WapUI: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0a x64 is not installed. " seems to really indicate .NET 2.0 is in the 32 bit version.